# Concatenate respective values ​from two columns, group them and add the repetition of their terms as a "multiple"

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In a spreadsheet I have the values ​​in column A and B and I want to reach the result in column D. In column C I have the formula below. This was the closest I could get to the desired result:

```
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" | "; TRANSPOR(SPLIT(B2; " | ";0)) & " " & TRANSPOR(SPLIT(A2; " | "))));LAMBDA(mem;SE(mem="";;
LET(cleaned; SUBSTITUIR(mem;" GB";"GB");
splitted; SPLIT(cleaned;" | ");
uniq; UNIQUE(TOCOL(splitted));
counts; BYROW(uniq;LAMBDA(each;CONT.SE(splitted;each)&" x "&each));
TEXTJOIN(" + ";1;counts)))))
```

Below is a representation of the spreadsheet:

| Interface HD | Capacidade HD | Result obtained with the above formula | Desired result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SATA | SATA/SSD | SATA | SATA | 500 GB | 240 GB | 500 GB | 500 GB | 3 x 500GB + 3 x SATA + 1 x 240GB + 1 x SATA/SSD | 1 x 240GB SATA/SSD + 3 x 500GB SATA |
| SATA/SSD | SATA | SATA | SATA/SSD | 256 GB | 500 GB | 500 GB | 256 GB | 2 x 256GB + 2 x SATA/SSD + 2 x 500GB + 2 x SATA | 2 x 256GB SATA/SSD + 2 x 500GB SATA |

The spreadsheet with the result presented above is this:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_pj1-xNqtwKB7nNF0lweuXV2X2FFRO2wCD1L-74Dek/edit?usp=sharing)

What change would be necessary in the formula in column C to arrive at the result in column D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `;0` in `splitted`.

```cpp
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" | "; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2; " | ";0)) & " " & TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2; " | "))));LAMBDA(mem;IF(mem="";;
LET(cleaned; SUBSTITUTE(mem;" GB";"GB");
splitted; SPLIT(cleaned;" | ";0);
uniq; UNIQUE(TOCOL(splitted));
counts; BYROW(uniq;LAMBDA(each;COUNTIF(splitted;each)&" x "&each));
TEXTJOIN(" + ";1;counts)))))
```

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  MAP(A2:A;B2:B;LAMBDA(int;cap;
    IFERROR(JOIN(" + ";BYROW(QUERY(TOCOL(SPLIT(cap;" | ";)&" "&SPLIT(int;" | ";));
       "select count(Col1),Col1 group by Col1 label count(Col1)''");LAMBDA(r;JOIN(" x ";r))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

*2 changes to current version*

- Change `SPLIT(cleaned;" | ")` to `SPLIT(cleaned;" | ";0)`
- Add `sort()` to second_internal `byrow()`

***Final formula***:

```
=BYROW(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" | "; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2; " | ";0)) & " " & TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2; " | "))));LAMBDA(mem;IF(mem="";;
LET(cleaned; SUBSTITUTE(mem;" GB";"GB");
splitted; SPLIT(cleaned;" | ";0);
uniq; UNIQUE(TOCOL(splitted));
counts; sort(BYROW(uniq;LAMBDA(each;COUNTIF(splitted;each)&" x "&each)));
TEXTJOIN(" + ";1;counts)))))
```

[image]